# I wanted to give up on recent changes and go back to the latest commit that had been pushed. Unstaged deleted:

Tags: git

I want to give up on recent changes and go back to the latest commit that had been pushed (2de1222).

Only one file was being worked on (unstaged) at that time. One local commit had been made since 2de1222. I made a gitk in a separate window so I could verify the SHAs of each commit and what the included files should look like.

First I tried `git reset 2de1222 --hard`. That gave me the message "fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree". So I did a 'git status' and it showed my one modified file but under "Changes not staged for commit" there was a long list of files which are all part of my app. A 'gitk' here shows that I am at the commit that I wanted to move to. The target file in the working directory looks as it should for commit 2de1222.

I searched for answers about similar messages and tried the following suggestions:

```
git checkout master

git reset --soft HEAD@{1}

git reset HEAD [my_filename]

git pull origin master

git reset --hard 2de1222  (different argument order)
```

In each case I got the same results from 'git status', along with that same warning: "fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree".
I don't really understand why git lists a bunch of supposed deletions and why I'm not in a "work tree".

How can I get back to the same state I was in immediately after the 2de1222 commit (where 'git status' shows no files) and be ready to change, test and commit the one file I need to? (hopefully without having to address each "deleted" file separately)?

Comment: Sounds like your repository is corrupt in some way. Delete the entire thing and `git clone` it again.

Comment: Since it was homework for an on-line class, I originally cloned from an earlier version and apparently I simply deployed from my local 2de1222 without first creating my own github repo for it.

Answer (score 4):

Using this:

```
git checkout -- .
```

will discard all the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in a source code directory with source when running these commands?  This is one reason this could happen, e.g. if you were in the .git directory.

Comment: I think I _was_ in the .git directory. How do I fix this?

Comment: Your .git directory and sub directories are under your source code directory, cd to the directory your source is in, and attempt the command(s) from there.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is what did it (just move out of the .git directory).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got out of the directory, renamed it to ...Old to try the cloning answer, and when I found I couldn't clone it (due to my own failure to push it earlier), I named it back and started to look at the files in the .git directory.

Everything looked okay there, and then when I went back to the directory in the terminal window and did a 'git status', all the spuriously "deleted" unstaged files were gone!

So I don't know what exactly fixed it (maybe it was just a git view problem) but everything does appear normal now.